# How to change the delimiter in C++ [for csv]

Tags: c++, export-to-csv

I'm trying to pass in data from a string into a .csv file, but I would like to know how i can change the delimiter from comma to any other char or even have no delimiters?

There will be commas in `data` thus other than stripping the commas, is it possible to remove delimiters/change the char of delimiters when writing to data.csv?

snippet of code:

```
string buffer, data;
ofstream oFile;
oFile.open("data.csv");
//some code to generate buffer
while (buffer.length() != 0){
   size_t pos = buffer.find("end");
   data = buffer.substr(0, pos);
   buffer.erase(0, pos);
   oFile << data;
   oFile << "\n";
}
oFile.close();
```

Comment: C++'s `ofstream` and `<<` do not know anything about the CSV format. It just writes the string as is. Please give an example of what `buffer` contains and how you want to change it.

Comment: Well, the short answer is "Of course", but that doesn't do you any good. Like your question, without example data, it is more of a hypothetical than anything else. Please provide your current format (show e.g. 10 lines of `data.csv`) and desired format noting whether there is any whitespace surrounding your delimters, etc... [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) needed.

Comment: `buffer` merely contains sentences like e.g. "The weather is good, I'd take a walk, then buy a drink". However, when passed into the `data.csv` it will show as 3 columns, but what i'm trying to achieve is the whole string as 1 col.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you output any comma in your code. Of course, when writing the file you can output any character as field separator.

The problem in your case may be with the code that *reads* the file. This is the place where you have to tell that the separator is something different than comma.

Maybe it helps to output your fields using double quotes? Then the reader may ignore the commas inside the quoted string.